# Onclick Validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I've been working on this assignment for the longest while. My form validations weren't working previously but then I found out what the error was & everything was working perfectly.

Later on, I had made some changes to the code then deleted those changes and now the validations aren't working again & I can't seem to find what the problem is this time.

Below is my unfinished code:

```js
 
    function validateEmail() {
    
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        if( email==null || email=="")
     {
     alert("Please input an email address");
     }
     }  

function validateFName() {

    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    if( firstname==null || firstname=="")
 {
 alert("Please input a last name");
 return false;
 }
 }
     function validateLName() {
    
        var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
        if( lastname==null || lastname=="")
     {
     alert("Please input a last name");
     }
     }
     
      function validateGender() {
    
        var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
        if( gender==null || gender=="")
     {
     alert("Please select a gender");
     }
     }
     
     
      function validateDate() {
    
        var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
        if( date==null || date=="")
     {
     alert("Please select a date");
     }
     }
     
      function validateVName() {
    
        var vname = document.getElementById('vname').value;
        if( vname==null || vname=="")
     {
     alert("Please input a victim's name");
     }
     }
     
     function validateVEmail() {
    
        var vemail = document.getElementById('vemail').value;
        if( vemail==null || vemail=="")
     {
     alert("Please input a victim's email");
     }
     }
```

```html
    <div id="navi">
      <nav>
    <ul class="fancyNav">
             <li id="home"><a href="#home" class="homeIcon">Home</a></li>
             <li id="news"><a href="#truth">TRUTH</a></li>
             <li id="about"><a href="#Dare">DARE</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      </div>
        
    <div id="box">
    <form id="truth">
    
    <h1> Truth </h1>
    <label> First Name: </label> <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" maxlength="30" placeholder="John" /> <br><br>
    <label> Last Name: </label> <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" maxlength="30" placeholder="Doe" /> <br><br>
    <label> Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  /> <br><br>
    <label> Male </label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male"/>
    <label> Female </label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female"/> <br><br>
    <label> Date to be performed: </label><input type="date" name="date" id="date" /><br><br>
    <h2> Victim </h2>
    <label> Name: </label>  <input type="text" name="vname" id="vname" maxlength="30" /><br><br>
     <label> Email:</label> <input type="text" name="vemail" id="vemail"  /> <br><br>
    
    
        <h2> Please select a truth questions below </h2> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q1"> Have you ever fallen and landed on your head? <br>
      
      <input type="radio"  name="truth" value="q2"> Have you ever return too much change? <br>
      
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q3"> Have you ever been admitted into the hospital? <br>
      
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q4"> Have you ever baked a cake? <br>
      
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q5"> Have you ever cheated on test? <br>
      
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q6"> Did you ever wish you were never born? <br>
      
      <input type="radio" name="truth" value="q7"> Did you ever hide from Sunday School? <br><br>
    
    <input type="submit" onclick="validateFName(); validateLName(); validateGender(); validateDate(); validateVName(); validateVEmail();" /> <br>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Describing specifically what you're expecting to happen and what is currently happening (or not happening), along with the minimal amount of code necessary to illustrate the issue would help.

Comment: followin link will definetly help..                                    http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptform.php

Comment: You need to prevent default behavior. This code will just submit the form.

Comment: @Vector..as answered by dinesh if OP will use `return false` default action of submit button will be prevented automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="validateFName(); validateLName(); validateGender(); v
```

typo in function name, onclick="validate**F**Name()...

it should be validate**L**Name()

and you define duplicate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> // remove this one
```

Comment: They are two different functions & I am required to add that additional tag.

Comment: have you solve your problem once you update the typo?

Comment: There is no type, they are two different functions. One is validateFName() and the other is validateLName().

Comment: But i can not find the definition of function validateFName() in the code you pasted

Comment: you can double check on this

Comment: Oh yeah, I see what you were referring to. I corrected it. It was there in my original code.

Answer (score 0):

The best possible solution would be to not use any `alert` boxes at all but instead embed the error message next to the place of the error, but that would be more involved. Instead, to stick with this solution, first add an id to your submit button:

```
<button type="submit" id="truth-submit">Submit</button>
```

Then, attach an `onclick` handler through JavaScript (and rewrite your code to be more re-usable):

```
// Only run when the window fully loads
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    function validateEmail() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        if (email === null || email === "") {
            return "Please input an email address";
        }
        return "";
    }

    function validateFName() {
        var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        if (firstname === null || firstname === "") {
            return "Please input an first name";
        }
        return "";
    }

    function validateLName() {
        var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
        if (lastname === null || lastname === "") {
            return "Please input an last name";
        }
        return "";
    }

    function validateGender() {
        var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
        if (gender === null || gender === "") {
            return "Please select a gender";
        }
        return "";
    }

    function validateDate() {
        var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
        if (date === null || date === "") {
            return "Please select a date";
        }
        return "";
    }

    function validateVName() {
        var vname = document.getElementById("vname").value;
        if (vname === null || vname === "") {
            return "Please input a victim's name";
        }
        return "";
    }

    function validateVEmail() {
        var vemail = document.getElementById("vemail").value;
        if (vemail === null || vemail === "") {
            return "Please input a victim's email";
        }
        return "";
    }

    document.getElementById("truth-submit").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        // Grab all of the validation messages
        var validationMessages = [validateFName(), validateLName(),
            validateGender(), validateDate(), validateVName(), validateVEmail()];

        var error = false;

        // Print out the non-blank ones
        validationMessages.forEach(function(message) {
            if (message) {
                alert(message);
                error = true;
            }
        });

        // Stop submission of the form if an error occurred
        if (error) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
}, false);
```